# Variable references question

Tags: javascript, reference

how come every time you make a change to one reference of a array it does not make a change on another either though both point to the same object.

Example:

```
myArray = new Array(5,5,5);
Array2 = new Array(7,7,7);
alert(myArray)  // still equals 5,5,5,`
```

Comment: why wouldn't myArray = 5,5,5?

Comment: Your question makes little sense: your two arrays are not the same object. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I just trying to understand reference values

Comment: You are declaring two new array objects... of course myArray will contain 5,5,5.

Comment: @James, you've asked 7 questions and accepted only 1 answer. Less than an hour you asked a question and were given a few excellent answers. Look at the length and detail of the big answer, that most certainly answers your question and more. It's expected behaviour that you reward such efforts with an accepted answer.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing issues with Array.prototype ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what's meant by *instances*. `Array` is a *constructor*. You create an *instance* by using the keyword `new`. So, using `var myArr = new Array(5,5,5)` the variable `myArr` is a reference to an *instance* created ('constructed') by the `Array` *constructor*.

In the case of Strings, Arrays and Objects using [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Literals) creates instances too, by the way:

```
var myArr = [5,5,5],
    myStr = '[5,5,5]',
    myObj = {myArr:[5,5,5]};
```

Answer (score 0):

By saying `new Array()` you are creating an entirely new array object, unrelated to the first. It would be like having two apples. Eating one has no effect on the other.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to ask here? It still equals `5,5,5`, because that's the array you are referencing! So, `myArray.toString()` will result in `5,5,5`, which is exactly what you get alerted.

You are instantiating two different objects there, so they are behaving the way they are expected to. They will never affect one another, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a bit of a misunderstanding about how references work. In your example, you create two distinct objects, and there are two variables referencing these objects. For a change on one variable to be reflected on another, you need two variables pointing to the same object, such as:

```
myArray = new Array(5);
myArray2 = myArray; // Now we have two variables pointing to same object
myArray2[2] = 4;
if (myArray[2] == 4) alert("Same value");
```